# Creating dict from csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am working with a csv file containing tweets which was generated using this project: https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python.

The 2 first tweets, and the headings in the csv file can be seen below:

```
username;date;retweets;favorites;text;geo;mentions;hashtags;id;permalink;;
thepsalami;02-04-2014 01:59;0;2;Must be #aprilfools because everyone is 
saying #HIMYM is over! Haha it'll never stop as long as we hold fast to the 
memories.;;;#aprilfools #HIMYM; 
4,51147E+17;https://twitter.com/thepsalami/status/451146992131923968;;
shahanasiddiqui;02-04-2014 01:59;0;0;@promahuq yeah B-R was no surprise - 
the ending was just right. My FB turned into #HIMYM blog site! Man that show 
had a huge impact!;;@promahuq;#HIMYM;4,51147E+17;https://twitter.com/shahanasiddiqui/status
/451146991955759105;;
```

I want to save this in a dict such that I can easily access e.g. the username, the time or the text. I tried using csv.DictReader:

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("HIMYM_tweets.csv"))
```

But that results in something very weird:

```
{'username;date;retweets;favorites;text;geo;mentions;hashtags;id;permalink;;': 
 "thepsalami;02-04-2014 01:59;0;2;Must be #aprilfools because everyone is 
 saying #HIMYM is over! Haha it'll never stop as long as we hold fast to the 
 memories.;;;#aprilfools #HIMYM; 4", None:['51147E+17;https://twitter.com/thepsalami/status/451146992131923968;;']}
{'username;date;retweets;favorites;text;geo;mentions;hashtags;id;permalink;;': '  ....
```

Any help on creating such a dict, or maybe doing something smarter is very appreciated :D

Comment: Hint: Look at the delimiter.

Comment: Ooh, so DictReader assumes that it is comma-seperated? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by David you need to consider the delimeter when using the DictReader.

Just replace your code with this and it should work

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("HIMYM_tweets.csv"),delimeter=";")
```